# Natural Language commands

Tags: nlp, command, chatbot

I would like to enrich my product with a sort of a "Power Search" bar. The idea comes from the Word feature "Tell me what you want to do", where Word suggests both actions, searching and help. I assume the actions come from some sort of natural language parsing. But I am not sure exactly what the term to look for is. My product is an online product hosted on AWS, so I would prefer to use a product from AWS if possible and not have to write this myself.

One example of what I would like to do is to map a command like `BookResource(string resource, date when)` to what is written by the user, who might type something like "Book room in two weeks" or maybe just "two weeks" or "next week". Another use case is also recognizing that the user typed a name and then booking on behalf of that user. The user does not exist in our system, so it is just a case of recognizing that it is a name and not something else.

But my problem is that I don't know what this technology is called. I have tried searching for natural language processing but haven't been able to find what I am looking for.

Can anyone tell me what this is called and also if there one or more services I can use from AWS that offers some of that functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I stumbled upon this, maybe it helps your case:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236858/build-a-natural-language-model-that-fixes-misspellings?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I think the misleading term is "natural language" which refers to "spoken language". Try "text" or "textual processing" instead.

The terms you are looking for on a more technical level would be "parsing", "lexer", "lambda function".

Try "text analyse API user input" maybe with "ChatBot" and/or "AWS".

This brought up a service named "Lex" on AWS on my search. Maybe this is what you need.